# Requesting data from multiple resources

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to acces multiple AzureAD resources in my Angular project. Currently I am requesting a local resource which is an API that provides all the data I need to display in the front-end of the application. The user can successfully sign in using AzureAD, which gets the token I use to retrieve data from the local API. For now this has been working fine and is used in production. However, to add new functionality to the application I am interested in using the Microsoft Graph API to get email, calendar and other data.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it working right, as I am only able to add one resource at a time. I can either get data from the local API or the graph api, but not at the same time. I hope someone can point me into the right direction and explain me how I can successfully connect with both API's using the same access token.

My OAuth2 configuration:

```
loginUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/authorize',
clientId: '{{clientid}}',
resource:  'https://{{domain}}.com/{{appid}}', //'https://graph.microsoft.com', 
logoutUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/logout',
redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/' + window.location.pathname,
silentRefreshRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-refresh.html',
timeoutFactor: 0.8,
scope: 'openid offline_access https://{{tenant}}.onmicrosoft.com/{{local-api}}/user_impersonation',
oidc: true,
issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/{{tenant}}/',
tokenEndpoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/token',
responseType: 'id_token token',
clearHashAfterLogin: true,
disableAtHashCheck: true,
showDebugInformation: true,
strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
```

Comment: Why not incorporate calling the Microsoft Graph in the existing API and returning the joined data from the backend? You could take a look at [HowTo: invite AAD user with Microsoft Graph](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/invite-aad-user-microsoft-graph/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't thought about it that way and it might be a possibility. However I think retrieving data from the front end might still be a better choice as the data I want to show is all related to the user that is currently signed in. It holds little connection to data that is returned from the local API. I have tried adding the delegated permission from the Graph API to the local API, forgot to mention that in the question. Unfortunately that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is to change the scope of your token. Your current token only supports openid and offline_access. You can find all the different permission settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).
Once you optain the correct token you can get the data that you asked for over the graph api.  [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0).

Keep in mind that your user will have to agree to give you permission to access this data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not seem to solve my issue as I am still unable to make a successful call to the Graph API. There is also no permission asked when I expand the scope with permissions from the Graph API